# What is the efficient way to find some pattern in a big text?

Tags: regex, text

I want to extract email addresses from a large text file. what is the best way to do it?

My idea is to find **'@'** in the text and use "Regex" to find email address into substring at (for example) 256 chars before this position and length of 512.

P.S.: Straightforwardly I want to know the best and most efficient way to find some pattern (like email addresses) in a *huge* text.

Comment: [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 1):

256 and 512 sound like arbitrary values.

- You could indeed scan for the @ sign,
  but then you'd have to read forward
  and backward until you encounter a
  character that is not allowed in an
  email address (for example, another @
  sign, a whitespace, a backslash...)
- Quoting wikipedia:

> The local-part of an e-mail address
>   may be up to 64 characters long and
>   the domain name may have a maximum of
>   255 characters.

So those values would be nicer.

Now combine both methods and voila, you have your algorithm.

Comment: There is also a maximum length of 254 bytes for email addresses *in toto*, as specified in RFC5321.  (This is 256 including the  `<` and `>` - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.3)

Comment: Thank you for your quotation. 64 and 256 is so better than 256 and 512 :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many false positives and false negatives you want.  Email addresses tend to be made up of letters, numbers, and certain symbols.  However, while it is probably extremely rare to see characters out of that set in a real email address, the standard [certainly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#RFC_specification) [allows it](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).  So you really need to decide how many real matches you want and how many matches you want that match your regular expression but are not actually email addresses.

Here's one answer excludes many valid cases and also probably includes too many:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&*+-=?^_~]{1,64}@[A-Za-z0-9-.]{1,255}\.[A-Z]{2,6}
```

Comment: Thank you but I know using of Regex. My question is about of finding email address in a huge text more than about email validation regex.

Comment: Salman, to me that sounds like a contradiction in terms: a regular expression _is_ a way to find e-mail addresses in a body of text. Might or might not be the best way, but you're talking about a really rare use case if they're not at least "good enough".

Comment: @Tomislav, Straightforwardly I want to know the best and most efficient way to find some pattern (like email addresses) in a huge text.

Comment: "The best and most efficient way" depends heavily on the nature of the text you're parsing and the nature of the addresses you're expecting to find. If you really want to squeeze it out of the CPU (assuming it's not I/O bound), you could read the text in manageable blocks look for an '@' sign and look for a first non-email-address character after it. You don't have to look for the first non-email-address character before '@' because you've already stored it's position, right? ;)

Comment: @Tomislav: The first non-email address character would not necessarily be known by the time the `@` is reached.  If it were, this would imply that every character before the `@` was checked to see if it was valid.  If the density of email addresses in the text is low, this check could slow down the process.  As you said, the solution really depends on the nature of the email addresses being found and the text being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need the most efficient way, I don't think regular expressions should be used.

Assuming almost all instances of `@` in your text are email addresses and you are working in a language with fast forward and backward string traversal, this method will probably be close to the fastest:

1. Search for `@`
2. Manually compare each character after the `@` to make sure they are within the allowed ASCII ranges
3. Keep track of whether a valid domain was found before the first space or other valid terminating character
4. Search again from the `@` symbol backwards, comparing each character to make sure they fall within the valid character ranges for the local component

Answer (score 0):

Locating all valid email addresses is not an easy thing to do as RFC for email address syntax is [quite complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378). If you just want to locate *normal* email addresses, you can use something like:

```
/(?<=^|[\s<(\["'])[a-z][\w.+-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?=[>)\]"']|$)/gi
```

This regex assumes that:

- Email address starts with a letter and contains only alphanumeric characters, period, underscores and hyphens (and one `@`, of course). It allows `+` in the name part.
- They are enclosed in whitespaces, square brackets, parentheses, single/double quotes or angle brackets

It doesn't check if the lengths of the name and domain parts are within their allowed range (and many other constraints set by RFC). Test it on a sample file and see how many emails it matches.

Comment: Thank you but I know using of Regex. My question is about of finding email address in a huge text more than about email validation regex.

Comment: @salman read a set of characters from the file (delimited by line breaks, or if your text is one huge line, then by spaces), and test each set against whatever regex you're comfortable with. It is straightforward.